# gcc -O4 optimization flag

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, compiler-construction

What's the meaning of the -O4 optimization flag in gcc (3.2.3)? What's the difference to O3? When would you use one vs. the other?

The man pages only mention O, O0-3, Os, no word of the mysterious O4. Thanks!

Comment: gcc 3.2.3 is positively archaic. Since then, the developers have released gcc 3.3, 3.4, 4.0, 4.1, 4.2, 4.3, 4.4, and 4.5. You should really use a more current release.

Comment: But the answer is the same for everything at least up to 4.4

Comment: Might be a leftover from the PGCC days which supported everything up to -O9.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There is no -O4 in 3.2.3.
Everything above -O3 results in -O3 being chosen.

Comment: Ok that would explain it. Would you happen to know if I can tell what O flag was used when something was compiled if I have the binary?

Comment: Some build systems insert the compiler settings into the binary, but there's no easy, generic way.

Comment: Is this still relevant as of gcc 5.3.0?

Answer (score 21):

You can check what optimization are enabled for each level

`gcc -c -Q -O3 --help=optimizers | grep enabled`

It works at least for gcc 4.4.