# Why does the compiler warn about uninitialized edge iterator in some optimization levels?

Tags: c++, boost, c++14

I have minimized the reproducible example as far as I was able to. In it, I loop over all edges in the boost graph and get a warning that I don't understand. Please explain to me why I am getting this warning, and perhaps also why it only appears in certain optimization levels.

```cpp
/*
 *  reproducing the warning about maybe uninitialized edge iterator
 */
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>

typedef boost::adjacency_list_traits<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS> traits;
typedef boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS, boost::no_property,
    boost::property<boost::edge_capacity_t, long>> graph;

typedef traits::vertex_descriptor vertex_desc;
typedef traits::edge_descriptor edge_desc;
typedef boost::graph_traits<graph>::edge_iterator edge_iterator;

int main(){
    // build a graph
    graph G(10);
    // get its capacity map
    auto c_map = boost::get(boost::edge_capacity, G);
    // get a handle to the first vertex
    vertex_desc source = boost::vertex(0, G);
    // add an edge, with a capacity of 1
    edge_desc e = boost::add_edge(boost::vertex(0, G), boost::vertex(1, G), G).first;
    c_map[e] = 1;
    // loop over all edges in the graph
    std::pair<edge_iterator, edge_iterator> eip = boost::edges(G);
    for (edge_iterator eit = eip.first; eit != eip.second; eit++){
        edge_desc e = *eit;
        vertex_desc a = boost::source(e, G);
        vertex_desc b = boost::target(e, G);
        bool source_involved = ((a == source) || (b == source));
        std::cout << (source_involved ? "yes" : "no") << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Compiled with `-O0` or `-O1`, there are no warnings:

```sh
g++ -std=c++14 -Wall -Wextra -O0 repro.cpp -o repro.exe
```

Compiled with `-O2` I get this warning:

```
# g++ -std=c++14 -Wall -Wextra -O2 repro.cpp -o repro.exe
repro.cpp: In function 'int main()':
repro.cpp:28:24: warning: '*((void*)& eit +48)' may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
     for (edge_iterator eit = eip.first; eit != eip.second; eit++){
                        ^~~
```

And compiled with `-O3`, `-O4`, `-O5` I get a similar warning, but in ugly:

```
# g++ -std=c++14 -Wall -Wextra -O3 repro.cpp -o repro.exe
repro.cpp: In function 'int main()':
repro.cpp:28:24: warning: '*((void*)(& eit)+32).__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<boost::detail::stored_edge_property<long unsigned int, boost::property<boost::edge_capacity_t, long int> >*, std::vector<boost::detail::stored_edge_property<long unsigned int, boost::property<boost::edge_capacity_t, long int> >, std::allocator<boost::detail::stored_edge_property<long unsigned int, boost::property<boost::edge_capacity_t, long int> > > > >::_M_current' may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
     for (edge_iterator eit = eip.first; eit != eip.second; eit++){
```

My `g++ --version` is

```
g++ (Ubuntu 8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04) 8.4.0
```

And I'm running in docker

```
# uname -a
Linux 88157d45c773 5.4.0-58-generic #64~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Dec 9 17:11:11 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

The warning does appear in `-std=c++11` and `-std=c++14` but not in `-std=c++17`, it seems.

What is this warning telling me? What is the issue?

Comment: Cannot reproduce: https://godbolt.org/z/c7c7z6. What is your version of Boost? I tried different ones from 1.64 to 1.75. It seems as if the constructor of `edge_iterator` does not initialize one of its member variables.

Comment: @DanielLangr in `/usr/include/boost/version.hpp` it defines `BOOST_LIB_VERSION` as `"1_65_1"`

Comment: @DanielLangr when I change the gcc version to `8.3` in your link, it shows the same warning https://godbolt.org/z/5Y4a45

Comment: I just found [an old email](https://lists.boost.org/boost-users/2015/07/84649.php) with a similar issue and no replies

Comment: Yeah, so this looks like an obvious compiler issue that has also since been fixed. I remember running into similar warning for a while. You should be able to silence it by marking the boost include as "system" includes, but whether or not that suits you is subjective

Comment: "compiled with ... -O4, -O5" woah! You're using [secret switches there... lightspeed!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3399821)

Comment: I can repoduce this [on godbolt with the latest version of Boost 1.75.0 and gcc up to version 9.3](https://godbolt.org/z/rjh147). However, i[t seems to be solved for 10.1 and up](https://godbolt.org/z/bdob57).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I commented, this is likely a compiler issue with specific compiler versions, where inlining+dead code elision leads to spurious unused variable warnings.

I don't see much virtue in finding whether there has been a bug report linked to the fix. Instead, let me show you more elegant ways to write the code in c++14.

> Not intended as an answer to the question as posed. though by sheer coincidence, the specific warnings you encounter might be gone.
>
> I post the answer for inspiration/educational value as I see a lot of copy/past BGL that is badly behind the times.

**[Live On Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/k511vHD67G0xbSDL)**

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using capacity_prop = boost::property<boost::edge_capacity_t, long>;

using graph = boost::adjacency_list<
                    boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS,
                    boost::no_property, capacity_prop
                >;

int main() {
    graph G(10);
    auto add = [&G](auto a, auto b, auto c) {
        add_edge(vertex(a, G), vertex(b, G), capacity_prop{c}, G);
    };
    add(0, 1, 1);
    add(1, 2, 2);
    add(1, 3, 3);
    add(1, 7, 4);
    add(1, 8, 5);
    add(2, 5, 6);
    add(5, 3, 7);
    add(5, 0, 8);
    add(7, 0, 9);

    auto const s = vertex(0, G);

    for (auto e : boost::make_iterator_range(edges(G))) {
        auto a = source(e, G);
        auto b = target(e, G);
        std::cout << e << " involves " << s << "? "
            << std::boolalpha << (a == s || b == s) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Prints

```
(0,1) involves 0? true
(1,2) involves 0? false
(1,3) involves 0? false
(1,7) involves 0? false
(1,8) involves 0? false
(2,5) involves 0? false
(5,3) involves 0? false
(5,0) involves 0? true
(7,0) involves 0? true
```

### C++17  Bonus

It would make it easier to write the initialization code more naturally

```
for (auto [a,b,c] : { std::tuple
        {0, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 2}, {1, 3, 3},
        {1, 7, 4}, {1, 8, 5}, {2, 5, 6},
        {5, 3, 7}, {5, 0, 8}, {7, 0, 9}, })
{
    add_edge(vertex(a, G), vertex(b, G), capacity_prop{c}, G);
}
```

### Logic Bonus

If really you wanted to find just the set of edges involving vertex `s`, you could write it like this and probably be more efficient:

**[Live On Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/XbtTb59EMfyZatFH)**

```
auto const s = vertex(2, G); // different example
auto [f,l] = out_edges(s, G);
edge_set involved(f, l);

for (auto e : make_iterator_range(edges(G)))
    if (target(e, G) == s)
        involved.insert(e);

for (auto e : involved)
    std::cout << e << " ";
```

Prints

```
(1,2) (2,5)
```

As one would expect.

### Performance Tip

If you can tweak the graph model, there's even better performance to be had by changing it to maintain bidirectional edges for the adjacency_list:

```
std::set<graph::edge_descriptor> involved;

auto insert = [&](auto range) { involved.insert(range.first, range.second); };
insert(out_edges(s, G));
insert(in_edges(s, G));
```

Or, indeed, just print them immediately:

```
for (auto e : make_iterator_range(out_edges(s, G)))
    std::cout << e << " ";
for (auto e : make_iterator_range(in_edges(s, G)))
    std::cout << e << " ";
```

See it **[Live Ob Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/XCTnqfImPr8E5KTc)**

Printing the same.

> Whether or not this improves performance for your application depends mostly on whether you have more mutations or more queries on the graph.

### PS

Here's the graph I made for the example for reference

[image]

This is the result of doing

```
boost::dynamic_properties dp;
dp.property("node_id", get(boost::vertex_index, G));
dp.property("label", get(boost::edge_capacity, G));
write_graphviz_dp(std::cout, G, dp);
```

And using `dot` (e.g. [online](https://dreampuf.github.io/GraphvizOnline/#digraph%20G%20%7B%0A0-%3E1%20%20%5Blabel%3D1%5D%3B%0A1-%3E2%20%20%5Blabel%3D2%5D%3B%0A1-%3E3%20%20%5Blabel%3D3%5D%3B%0A1-%3E7%20%20%5Blabel%3D4%5D%3B%0A1-%3E8%20%20%5Blabel%3D5%5D%3B%0A2-%3E5%20%20%5Blabel%3D6%5D%3B%0A5-%3E3%20%20%5Blabel%3D7%5D%3B%0A5-%3E0%20%20%5Blabel%3D8%5D%3B%0A7-%3E0%20%20%5Blabel%3D9%5D%3B%0A%7D%0A))

Comment: Added a [visual rendering](https://dreampuf.github.io/GraphvizOnline/#digraph%20G%20%7B%0A0-%3E1%20%20%5Blabel%3D1%5D%3B%0A1-%3E2%20%20%5Blabel%3D2%5D%3B%0A1-%3E3%20%20%5Blabel%3D3%5D%3B%0A1-%3E7%20%20%5Blabel%3D4%5D%3B%0A1-%3E8%20%20%5Blabel%3D5%5D%3B%0A2-%3E5%20%20%5Blabel%3D6%5D%3B%0A5-%3E3%20%20%5Blabel%3D7%5D%3B%0A5-%3E0%20%20%5Blabel%3D8%5D%3B%0A7-%3E0%20%20%5Blabel%3D9%5D%3B%0A%7D%0A) of my sample graph for convenience

Comment: Thank you! This is a collection that would have been very nice to have when I first started (and I'm still disappointed my university didn't provide a better intro). I learned about the `add_edge()` with properties earlier today - but with round parentheses. Does that make a difference? And what is the advantage of the `make_iterator_range`?

Comment: @lucidbrot In most cases it doesn't make a difference. But `{}` is known as [uniform initialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Uniform_initialization) and has some perks (like [anonymous initializers: `{c}`](https://wandbox.org/permlink/SEvWkTULqV1n5k84)).

Comment: `make_iterator_range` is the easiest way to enjoy [range-for](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) which greatly simplifies the for loops on iterator pairs. BGL's interface returns flat `std::pair` of iterators, which does not automatically afford range-for loops.

Comment: I have now accepted this answer as the proposed workaround with `make_iterator_range` actually gets rid of the warning and makes the results be consistent between different optimization levels.